# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-qunit`. Odd out-of-the-box ember-cli behavior

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I believe I may have an environment issue here, but I'm quite stuck as to what I can to do resolve it.  I created an ember-cli project, committed it to git, added a few things.  I ran the typical `npm install && bower install` commands and tried `ember s`.

Although the site loads fine, when I browsed to the http://localhost:4200/tests/ to ensure qunit was up and running, I had a few errors.

`` Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-qunit` imported from `ember-project/tests/test-helper ``

`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests index.html includes "assets/tests.js".`

Immediately this raised a red flag, as I have created several ember projects before and not run into similar issues.  I had my partners (I'm in school) checkout the project, run the `npm install && bower install && ember s` and the qunit module worked fine for them!

I've tried to git clone a new repo several times, I've even went so far as to uninstall node and bower completely, but no matter what I try I cannot seem to pull up a normal /tests checkout.

My partners were both running VMs - Ubuntu and Debian, while I'm on a mac, but that seems like it shouldn't be too big of an issue, especially *since I created the project!*

I've looked several places for this ([here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5084), [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5093), and [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/3070653-after-one-require-error-subsequent-ones-fail-to-load-uncaught-error-could-not-find-module-ember-qunit)), but I cannot seem to come to a conclusion which works for me.

I do have an identical bower.json as the rest of my group.  I've included the picture below of my file structure, my bower.json, and my tests/index.html.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwYY9.jpg)

Here are some environment stats:

```
ember version: 1.13.13
node: 5.0.0
os: darwin x64
bower: 1.7.1
```

One thing that I did notice is a difference when I do this to see npm's version, but I'm not sure if that matters or not.

```
ember -v
  npm: 2.14.10
npm -v
  npm: 3.5.2
```

Comment: I'm able to take my bower_components folder from my partner and overwrite my own bower_components folder and it seems to work.  I'm going to have to diff the two directories to see what's happening.  It's not an answer yet, but I've significantly narrowed down the problem.

Comment: Also having this issue after upgrading to the newest ember-cli. Bower.json file seems to drop "ember-qunit" from dependencies and package.json seems to pull in "ember-cli-qunit". However the "ember-qunit" package isn't being resolved or found. An answer to this problem would be great.

Comment: Getting this error as well

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a regression from the work in ember-cli beta. You can track the progress here https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5411.
For now, you can add

```
  app.import('bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.js');
  app.import('bower_components/ember-qunit/ember-qunit.amd.js');
```

to `ember-cli-build.js` as a workaround.